# Why FILTER_VALIDATE_DOMAIN allow character like dot, emoji, empty value, special char?

Tags: php, filter-var

I've had used the FILTER_VALIDATE_DOMAIN to validate domain but it allow the all character like space, special character, empty value seems like not working

here are some examples all return none bool value.

```
var_dump(filter_var("0", FILTER_VALIDATE_DOMAIN));
var_dump(filter_var('test', FILTER_VALIDATE_DOMAIN));
var_dump(filter_var('test test', FILTER_VALIDATE_DOMAIN));
var_dump(filter_var('@', FILTER_VALIDATE_DOMAIN));
var_dump(filter_var('', FILTER_VALIDATE_DOMAIN));
```

I expect that should be return false.

Comment: You did read the docs, right?

Comment: Maybe you forgot to add the `FILTER_FLAG_HOSTNAME`....check how it works https://ideone.com/WzbmyV

Comment: @Hackerman I see it look like partially working. See the top 2 lines that also should return the false. We expect the .(dot) in domain name.

Answer (score 5):

Insert the condition FILTER_FLAG_HOSTNAME

```
var_dump(filter_var("0", FILTER_VALIDATE_DOMAIN, FILTER_FLAG_HOSTNAME));
var_dump(filter_var('test', FILTER_VALIDATE_DOMAIN, FILTER_FLAG_HOSTNAME));
var_dump(filter_var('test test', FILTER_VALIDATE_DOMAIN, FILTER_FLAG_HOSTNAME));
var_dump(filter_var('@', FILTER_VALIDATE_DOMAIN, FILTER_FLAG_HOSTNAME));
var_dump(filter_var('', FILTER_VALIDATE_DOMAIN, FILTER_FLAG_HOSTNAME));
```